# How we feel (perceive) exact size of object through our eyes?

Tags: visible-light, photons, vision, perception

Light after getting reflected from objects gets focused on retina by our lens. The images formed on retina is small, which is then sensed by our brain and depending on distance we feel size of that object.

If an object is at particular distance from us, the image on retina is not going to be the exact size which we feel by our eyes after sensed by our brain. Our  brain predicts size depending on the distance that brain sensed. But why the size we feel by our eyes is same as the size we feel by touch. Like if we see an object we can feel its boundary, and if we touch it and sense the boundary it does not extend or change.

Why the boundary of object we feel by eyes doesn't contradict reality?

Comment: Are you asking about depth perception?

Comment: No size of object

Comment: So you are asking about size perception. This is not a physics question.

Comment: of cause it is a physics question , even if  at some point the brain an biologie is involved.

Answer (score 3):

One eye perceives the angular size of an object.  With two eyes we can get an estimate of the distance to the object. In combination these can let us estimate the actual size.  Our estimate of size will often be dependent on the context in which the object is observed.

Answer (score 2):

As R.W. Bird said, our 2 eyes give us a perception of distance for not too far objects. Our brain uses that information and the apparent size to estimate the real size.

But it doesn't work for distant objects. The moon and the sun have almost the same (apparent) size. When guided only by perception, we are completely unable to estimate their real sizes.